# python version doesn't update on OS X

Tags: macos, python-3.x, upgrade

I've just installed python 3.3.3 on my OS X 10.9.1, however when I run python from the terminal the version that is indicated is 2.7.5. What have I done wrong and how can I make it right?

Comment: Use the right path; you are running the OS X `/usr/bin/python` interpreter. Try `python3` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Martijn Pieters's comment, I used `python3` and now it works as expected.